# How to run youtube videos

Tags: php, youtube, proxy

Hello everyone I am a beginner in php. I need help. I analyze and research that youtube have two types of video id

1) HPEeQwbTLT8
2) ijLZ9-rlEhg

No. 1 is running good in my proxy script.

http://experiment.letwatchus.com/videos/getvideo.php?videoid=HPEeQwbTLT8&type=Download

No. 2 which have dash (-) my php script is unable to download these type of id videos

http://experiment.letwatchus.com/videos/getvideo.php?videoid=ijLZ9-rlEhg&type=Download

if you check above link 2nd link will not download the video but first link will running well.

and another proxy server run these both id well. This proxy server is running good with above both id.

needunblock.com

I don't know how they can process No. 2 dash type id of video please help me and give me an idea what is happening.

**getvideo.php file code are as follow.**

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
ob_start();// if not, some servers will show this php warning: header is already set in line 46...

function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) { 
    $units = array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'); 
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0); 
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024)); 
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1); 
    $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);
    return round($bytes, $precision) . '' . $units[$pow]; 
} 
function is_chrome(){
    $agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if( preg_match("/like\sGecko\)\sChrome\//", $agent) ){  // if user agent is google chrome
        if(!strstr($agent, 'Iron')) // but not Iron
            return true;
    }
    return false;   // if isn't chrome return false
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['videoid'])) {
    $my_id = $_REQUEST['videoid'];
    if(strlen($my_id)>11){
        $url   = parse_url($my_id);
        $my_id = NULL;
        if( is_array($url) && count($url)>0 && isset($url['query']) && !empty($url['query']) ){
            $parts = explode('&',$url['query']);
            if( is_array($parts) && count($parts) > 0 ){
                foreach( $parts as $p ){
                    $pattern = '/^v\=/';
                    if( preg_match($pattern, $p) ){
                        $my_id = preg_replace($pattern,'',$p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( !$my_id ){
                echo '<p>No video id passed in</p>';
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            echo '<p>Invalid url</p>';
            exit;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>No video id passed in</p>';
    exit;
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['type'])) {
    $my_type =  $_REQUEST['type'];
} else {
    $my_type = 'redirect';
}

if ($my_type == 'Download') {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }

    .download {
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 19px 29px 29px;
            margin: 0 auto 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
               -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
               -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }

      .download .download-heading {
            text-align:center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .mime, .itag {
            width: 75px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .itag {
            width: 15px;
      }

      .size {
            width: 20px;
      }

      .userscript {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 5px
      }

      #info {
            padding: 0 0 0 130px;
            position: relative;
            height:100px;
      }

      #info img{
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width:120px;
            height:90px
      }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="download">
<?php
} // end of if for type=Download

/* First get the video info page for this video id */
//$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='. $my_id;
$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='. $my_id.'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US'; //video details fix *1

$my_video_info = curlGet($my_video_info);

/* TODO: Check return from curl for status code */

$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';

parse_str($my_video_info);

echo '<div id="info">';
switch($config['ThumbnailImageMode'])
{
  case 2: echo '<a href="getimage.php?videoid='. $my_id .'&sz=hd" target="_blank"><img src="getimage.php?videoid='. $my_id .'" border="0" hspace="2" vspace="2"></a>'; break;
  case 1: echo '<a href="getimage.php?videoid='. $my_id .'&sz=hd" target="_blank"><img src="'. $thumbnail_url .'" border="0" hspace="2" vspace="2"></a>'; break;
  case 0:  default:  // nothing
}
echo '<p>'.$title.'</p>';
echo '</div>';

$my_title = $title;
$cleanedtitle = clean($title);

if(isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
    /* Now get the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, and explode on comma */
    $my_formats_array = explode(',',$url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
    if($debug) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($my_formats_array);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>No encoded format stream found.</p>';
    echo '<p>Here is what we got from YouTube:</p>';
    echo $my_video_info;
}
if (count($my_formats_array) == 0) {
    echo '<p>No format stream map found - was the video id correct?</p>';
    exit;
}

/* create an array of available download formats */
$avail_formats[] = '';
$i = 0;
$ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
$expire = time(); 

foreach($my_formats_array as $format) {
    parse_str($format);
    $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
    $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
    $type = explode(';',$type);
    $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
    $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
    parse_str(urldecode($url));
    $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
    $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
    $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
    $i++;
}

if ($debug) {
    echo '<p>These links will expire at '. $avail_formats[0]['expires'] .'</p>';
    echo '<p>The server was at IP address '. $avail_formats[0]['ip'] .' which is an '. $avail_formats[0]['ipbits'] .' bit IP address. ';
    echo 'Note that when 8 bit IP addresses are used, the download links may fail.</p>';
}
if ($my_type == 'Download') {
    echo '<p align="center">List of available formats for download:</p>
        <ul>';

    /* now that we have the array, print the options */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($avail_formats); $i++) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span class="itag">' . $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] . '</span> ';
        if($config['VideoLinkMode']=='direct'||$config['VideoLinkMode']=='both')
          echo '<a href="' . $avail_formats[$i]['url'] . '&title='.$cleanedtitle.'" class="mime">' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] . '</a> ';
        else
          echo '<span class="mime">' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] . '</span> ';
        echo '<small>(' .  $avail_formats[$i]['quality'];
        if($config['VideoLinkMode']=='proxy'||$config['VideoLinkMode']=='both')
            echo ' / ' . '<a href="download.php?mime=' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] .'&title='. urlencode($my_title) .'&token='.base64_encode($avail_formats[$i]['url']) . '" class="dl">download</a>';
        echo ')</small> '.
            '<small><span class="size">' . formatBytes(get_size($avail_formats[$i]['url'])) . '</span></small>'.
        '</li>';
    }
    //echo '</ul><small>Note that you initiate download either by clicking video format link or click "download" to use this server as proxy.</small>';

//  if(($config['feature']['browserExtensions']==true)&&(is_chrome()))
  //  echo '<a href="ytdl.user.js" class="userscript btn btn-mini" title="Install chrome extension to view a \'Download\' link to this application on Youtube video pages."> Install Chrome Extension </a>';
?>

</body>
</html>

<?php

} else {

/* In this else, the request didn't come from a form but from something else
 * like an RSS feed.
 * As a result, we just want to return the best format, which depends on what
 * the user provided in the url.
 * If they provided "format=best" we just use the largest.
 * If they provided "format=free" we provide the best non-flash version
 * If they provided "format=ipad" we pull the best MP4 version
 *
 * Thanks to the python based youtube-dl for info on the formats
 *                              http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/
 */

$format =  $_REQUEST['format'];
$target_formats = '';
switch ($format) {
    case "best":
        /* largest formats first */
        $target_formats = array('38', '37', '46', '22', '45', '35', '44', '34', '18', '43', '6', '5', '17', '13');
        break;
    case "free":
        /* Here we include WebM but prefer it over FLV */
        $target_formats = array('38', '46', '37', '45', '22', '44', '35', '43', '34', '18', '6', '5', '17', '13');
        break;
    case "ipad":
        /* here we leave out WebM video and FLV - looking for MP4 */
        $target_formats = array('37','22','18','17');
        break;
    default:
        /* If they passed in a number use it */
        if (is_numeric($format)) {
            $target_formats[] = $format;
        } else {
            $target_formats = array('38', '37', '46', '22', '45', '35', '44', '34', '18', '43', '6', '5', '17', '13');
        }
    break;
}

/* Now we need to find our best format in the list of available formats */
$best_format = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($target_formats); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < count ($avail_formats); $j++) {
        if($target_formats[$i] == $avail_formats[$j]['itag']) {
            //echo '<p>Target format found, it is '. $avail_formats[$j]['itag'] .'</p>';
            $best_format = $j;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

//echo '<p>Out of loop, best_format is '. $best_format .'</p>';
if( (isset($best_format)) && 
  (isset($avail_formats[$best_format]['url'])) && 
  (isset($avail_formats[$best_format]['type'])) 
  ) {
    $redirect_url = $avail_formats[$best_format]['url'].'&title='.$cleanedtitle;
    $content_type = $avail_formats[$best_format]['type'];
}
if(isset($redirect_url)) {
    header("Location: $redirect_url"); 
}

} 
?>
```

**download.php code :**

**

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
// Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
    exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}
// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 
// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
    $size=get_size($url);
    // Generate the server headers
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== TRUE)
    {
        header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Pragma: public');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
    }
    readfile($url);
    exit;
}
// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
```

**

Friends I have debugging my code and when I hit no. 1 id size is given but in no.2 I did'nt get any size I think thats why 2nd link type not downloaded.
here is my function of getting size .

```
function get_size($url) {
    $my_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
    curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
    curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    $r = curl_exec($my_ch);
     foreach(explode("\n", $r) as $header) {
        if(strpos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            return trim(substr($header,16)); 
        }
     }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Include some of your code

Comment: ok i am adding my get_video.php

Comment: @Epodax i have added my code and i also debug it in 2nd type of youtube video id my code not return file size i think this is why it is not downloading

Answer (score 0):

A PHP example for extracting the video id is as follows:

```
<?php
    preg_match(
        '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzHvVoUGTOM&feature=channel',
        $matches
    );
    // $matches[1] should contain the youtube id
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<embed width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wHdSkyhuocM">
```